# How to use "bring [somebody/something] back"?

Tags: vocabulary

Can I use "bring [somebody/something] back" in either way as follows:

> 1. His music always **brings** me **back** to last winter.
> 2. His music always **brings** memories in last winter **back**.

Can I use a *phrasal verb* **"bring [sb/sth] back"** in both of these ways?

And do sentence 1 and 2 deliver the same meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost yes. (You've used the wrong preposition in your second sentence.)

This first sentence is fine as-is:

> His music always brings me back to last winter.

Here is another example usage of that construct, taken from a [college newspaper](https://codcourier.org/10442/showcase/the-courier-staffs-favorite-nostalgic-songs/):

> This song **brings me back to** the winter of my senior year of high school, just a few months before I was going to graduate.

As for your second sentence, change the *in* to *of* and it sounds just fine:

> His music always brings memories of last winter back.

We typically have memories *of* something, not memories *in* something. Here is a [quote](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/151476-only-once-in-your-life-i-truly-believe-you-find) by the musician Bob Marley:

> The things that seem insignificant to most people such as a note, song or walk become invaluable treasures kept safe in your heart to cherish forever. Memories **of** your childhood come back and are so clear and vivid it’s like being young again.

Comment: In my experience, "brings memories back" is a lot less common than "brings back memories". I've never heard or read "brings memories back" for anything other than to convey the reverse of amnesia.

Comment: @mRotten - Great point, and I concur. An improved wording would be: _His music always brings back memories of last winter._